# FATAL EXCEPTION при снимке второй фотографии

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Делаю несколько фотографий камерой, на 5 версии Android все работает, на 4 версии получаю при снимке второй фотографии:

**java.lang.RuntimeException:FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                         Process: com.example.attracti.audiorecorderpicture, PID: 5902                                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed**

В проекте используется камера, которая уже `deprecated`: `android.hardware.Camera`.

Падает на строчке:

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() { 
...
}
```

Вопрос, что делать в этой ситуации? Переписывать весь код с новой камерой? или есть какой-то лайфхак для 4 версии Android?

Полный стактрейс ошибки:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.attracti.audiorecorderpicture, PID: 27720
java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
   at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
   at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1651)
   at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1596)
   at com.example.audiorecorderpicture.fragments.CameraFragment.captureImage(CameraFragment.java:294)
   at com.example.audiorecorderpicture.fragments.CameraFragment.takePicture(CameraFragment.java:399)
   at com.example.audiorecorderpicture.activities.AudioRecordActivity$1.onClick(AudioRecordActivity.java:393)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5300)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:830)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:646)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: полный стактрейс ошибки пожалуйста приведите...

Comment: @metalurgus  добавила. Возможно, проблема еще в PictureCallback(), который уже тоже deprecated.

Comment: @Lucky_girl Возможное решение проблемы http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723557/java-lang-runtimeexception-takepicture-failed